# In sybase 12.5, can I have some SQL to get the Nth to Mth row?

Tags: sap-ase

In sybase 12.5 (ASE, not Sql Anywhere), 
can I use some (ANSI) SQL to get the Nth to Mth row ?

Otherwise, a pointer to a non-ANSI way will help, I can't find it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
select rownum=identity(10), t.* into #temp from tablename t

select * from #temp where rownum between 5 and 10

drop table #temp
```

Replace `5` and `10` by the Nth and Mth values.

Comment: Is there a way to not have this tmp table ?

Comment: this aspect of Sybase is a little limited I think... :) Well, I'm still happy to have a solution, I was almost afraid there was none for a moment.

Comment: In Sybase ASE really don't know how to do it without using a #temp table. In Sybase IQ it's possible but here I don't think so. If this works for you, then accept it :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work